# Why links in polymer library doesn't working until you add target="_self"

Tags: hyperlink, polymer, web-deployment, web-component, polymer-starter-kit

My test site is a bit modified version of polymer starter kit (advanced version)

And links won't work until you manually add `target="_self"` or another attribute even though:

> - ripples effect happens when you click the button
> - as well as link indication appears (the tiny link in the bottom edge of the browser when you hover the button)

Sample code of the button

```
<paper-button>
    <a href="{{baseUrl}}contact.html" target="_self">Contact</a>
</paper-button>
```

I have `bower_components` directory in `app` folder of my project and it's full of all those elements by default, but do I need to `bower <component name> install` it before using or something like that or what else might causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, to use a Polymer element on a page, the element should be available to be imported into the page. This typically means you'll have done a couple things:

1. Run `bower install --save-dev <element-name>`. The exact Bower command to run can be copied from the Polymer element's [docs page](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-button) (bottom left):

[image]

2. Import the element into the page with a `<link>` tag (e.g., `<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">`).

One of the nice things about Polymer Starter Kit is that its [setup](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit#install-dependencies) includes downloading all [Paper Elements](https://elements.polymer-project.org/browse?package=paper-elements) from bower (including `paper-button`). So, in your case, you do **not** need to run `bower install` to use `paper-button`. The fact that you see a ripple upon clicking the button implies that you already have the `paper-button` element downloaded and the `link` import.

#### Testing

I just appended a `paper-button` with a target-less link to the drawer in `index.html`:

```html
<body unresolved>
...
    <paper-drawer-panel id="paperDrawerPanel">
      <paper-scroll-header-panel drawer fixed>
...
        <paper-menu attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="[[route]]">
...
          <!-- Your code below... -->
          <paper-button>
            <a href="{{baseUrl}}contact">Contact!</a>
          </paper-button>
        </paper-menu>
      </paper-scroll-header-panel>
...
</body>
```

and it worked fine:

[image]

(We'll need more context to determine the cause of your problem...)

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer and tony19, thank you for the answers I should've mention that I didn't use routing and binding, I placed a paper-button on the page without iron tags. I was just trying to make direct links to .html page to work. I'm new to development and I'm afraid my question was stupid and all I had to do is to stick with target in this case anyway, but I thought that it is not working because it might be a bug or I messed some routing stuff that will influence security of my site or something like that. Anyway If there any additional comments on that I would appreciate that as well

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this fixes your issue but

For binding to `href` use attribute binding syntax

```
<a href$="{{baseUrl}}contact.html">Contact</a>
```

otherwise some browsers try to resolve the value `"{{baseUrl}}contact.html"` before Polymer had a chance to resolve the binding and assign the calculated URL.

See also at the end of this  section https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#property-binding

> Some attributes are special. When binding to style, href, class, for or data-* attributes, it is recommend that you use [attribute binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#attribute-binding) syntax. For more information, see [Binding to native element attributes](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#native-binding).

Comment: Günter Zöchbauer thank you for the answer, I added some information to the comment above, if you have any additional thoughts on that I would glad to see them too.

Comment: This code `href="{{baseUrl}}contact.html"` from your question actually uses binding. Is this not what you're question is about? What do you actually try to accomplish? Are you aware that such a link navigates away from the current application to a different application (page). Is this what you want? In a Polymer [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) you usually just replace one component by another instead of navigating to a different page which results in an entire page reload.

Comment: Well, I meant I've deleted the route attributes from buttons. 

And a link won't work if I do this

`<paper-button>

<a href="http://localhost:5000/contact.html">contact</a>

</paper-button>`
instead of 

`{{baseUrl}}contact.html`
as well.

And I've tried to use route and it was faster than switching .html pages via link, but I couldn't understand how to fix the following issue: when I switched from home to contact page it's ok, the url updates but then click to home button from the contact page and it still shows site.com/contact instead of site.com/

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with routing. Haven't use the router yet.